# Splitting each key's value in a list of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I want to split each key's value in a list of a dictionary in python. How can I do that.
Suppose I have the following dictionary,

```
dic = {'a': '12 34 12','b':'23 43 12','c':'21' }
```

I want to convert it into,

```
dic = {'a': [12,34,12],'b':[23,43,12],'c':[21] }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: use `str.split` on the key's value and convert each item to int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways. One solution is that you can seperate each value using `split()` function and assign the splited value to  corresponding keys, as follows:

```
dic = {'a': '12 34 12','b':'23 43 12','c':'21' }

for key, value in dic.items():
    dic[key] = value.split()

print(dic)
# {'a': ['12', '34', '12'], 'b': ['23', '43', '12'], 'c': ['21']}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the dictionary and cast to integer values with a list comprehension:

```
dic = {'a': '12 34 12','b':'23 43 12','c':'21' }
for i in dic:
  dic[i] = [int(a) for a in dic[i].split(" ")]
  #dic[i] = list(map(int, dic[i].split(" "))) #Alternative using map()
print(dic)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': [12, 34, 12], 'b': [23, 43, 12], 'c': [21]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split(" ")` which splits on a single whitespace character. If you have more than one you might want to use regex and `\s+`. I've also added a list comprehension to convert to integer values since your expected output formatted it that way. Hope this helps!

```py
dic = {'a': '12 34 12','b':'23 43 12','c':'21' }

for k in dic:
    # dic[k] = dic[k].split(" ") # if you're okay with strings

    # if you want conversion to int
    dic[k] = [int(i) for i in dic[k].split(" ")]

print(dic)
# >>> {'a': [12, 34, 12], 'b': [23, 43, 12], 'c': [21]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oneliner version using both list and dictionary comprehension.

```py
{k: [int(x) for x in v.split()] for k, v in dic.items()}
```

The `for k, v in dic.items()` iterate through the keys and values of the dict.

While the `[int(x) for x in v.split()]` part constructs a list from the `str.split` results of the values and map them as ints.

You get the expected result:

```py
{'a': [12, 34, 12], 'b': [23, 43, 12], 'c': [21]}
```

I hope every part is clear! These comprehensions are a key element of python language, so leave a comment if a point is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is to use **dictionary comprehension**:

```
a = {'a': '12 34 12','b':'23 43 12','c':'21' }
a = {key: list(map(int, val.split())) for key, val in a.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': [12, 34, 12], 'b': [23, 43, 12], 'c': [21]}
```

You can use the `split()` function to make a list out of your list. Then use map to make an integer of each of your list items, since they are stored as strings. Lastly, use list around map, since map returns a map object, not a list.

Hope this helps! Please ask if anything is unclear.